# Set length() as variable and use later in select statement

Tags: mysql, variables

I would like to set a variable in a mysql query and use the output of that variable function within the length function as follows.

```
> SET @si_len :=  length(w.short_identifier);
SELECT   left(e.reference_number,@si_len) AS 'cut_OUT'
FROM table1 e 
        left join table2 w 
            on e.table1_id = w.table2id
```

Any suggestions? This returns all NULL

Comment: what's the structures of your tables.

Comment: Hey, Im not sure i get what ure asking. Table 1 and table 2 joins together as in the statement. Short_identifier  is varchar and reference_number also

Comment: Well, length function is used to get the length of a `string`, how can you get the length of a column if you use this function?

Comment: is there no way that it can work row by row

Comment: Certainly there is a way.Try this: SELECT left(e.reference_number,length(w.short_identifier)) AS 'cut_OUT'

Comment: Cooool, Never Tried that. Thank you so much